# Union two tables and convert XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2016

I have two tables which contain the product information of Type1 and Type2 and one common table which has rate information.

Consider the following table structures

Table #1 `Type1Product`:

```
Id        Name               TAX    Model    Class
___________________________________________________
GUID 1    Type1_Product_1    5      SUX      XI
GUID 2    Type1_Product_2    5      SUX      XII
GUID 3    Type1_Product_3    5      SUX      X
GUID 4    Type1_Product_4    5      SUX      XIII
```

Table #2 `Type2Product`:

```
Id        Name               TAX    Catalog
___________________________________________________
GUID 5    Type2_Product_1    5      IXM
GUID 6    Type2_Product_2    5      IXM
GUID 7    Type2_Product_3    5      IXM
GUID 8    Type2_Product_4    5      IXM
```

Table #3 `Rate`:

```
Id         ProductId          Rate
___________________________________________________
GUID 11    GUID 1             15
GUID 12    GUID 2             25
GUID 13    GUID 3             33
GUID 14    GUID 4             11
GUID 15    GUID 5             5
GUID 16    GUID 6             8
GUID 17    GUID 7             2
GUID 18    GUID 8             4
```

Now I have the following SQL `SELECT` query with UNION

```
SELECT 
    t1.Id, t1.Name, rt.Rate 
FROM 
    Rate rt 
INNER JOIN 
    Type1Product t1 ON t1.Id = rt.ProductId

UNION

SELECT 
    t2.Id, t2.Name, rt.Rate 
FROM 
    Rate rt 
INNER JOIN 
    Type2Product t2 ON t2.Id = rt.ProductId
FOR XML PATH ('Product'), ELEMENTS, root ('Root')
```

Note: `GUID` is an unique identifier "GUID 1" represents an unique Identifier, for easy understanding I used the the keywords like "GUID 1"

I'm getting error while on execution

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

Kindly assist me.

Comment: For xml *  work with  just have a single result set  you can use CTE or Sub query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
with tamp as (

        SELECT 
            t1.Id, t1.Name, rt.Rate 
        FROM 
            Rate rt 
        INNER JOIN 
            Type1Product t1 ON t1.Id = rt.ProductId

        UNION

        SELECT 
            t2.Id, t2.Name, rt.Rate 
        FROM 
            Rate rt 
        INNER JOIN 
            Type2Product t2 ON t2.Id = rt.ProductId
    )

    select * from temp  FOR XML PATH ('Product'), ELEMENTS, root ('Root')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your Union statement in a single SELECT statement like this

```
SELECT(
SELECT * 
FROM(
SELECT 
    t1.Id, t1.Name, rt.Rate 
FROM 
    Rate rt 
INNER JOIN 
    Type1Product t1 ON t1.Id = rt.ProductId

UNION

SELECT 
    t2.Id, t2.Name, rt.Rate 
FROM 
    Rate rt 
INNER JOIN 
    Type2Product t2 ON t2.Id = rt.ProductId

) D
FOR XML PATH ('Product'), ELEMENTS, root ('Root')
) AS XMLout
```